# Beego orm orderby rand()

Tags: go, beego

I just ran into some problem in beego orm.
how to make a query with random order?

something like:

`orm.NewOrm().QueryTable("tbl").OrderBy("rand()").Limit(1).All(&table)`

but it gives panic result

I look at the documentation, but can't find that work for random result. any help is much appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

BeeGo ORM doesn't support ordering by methods, only by mapped fields:

https://github.com/astaxie/beego/blob/master/orm/db_tables.go#L434